# Importing Global SCSS into Component SCSS with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular-cli

Is there an easy way to import global variables into components? I have tried importing my `variables.scss` file every way I can. Here's the basic app structure:

```
| app
  | components
    | component
      | component.scss
| scss
  | variables.scss
```

The only way I can get this to work is  `@import '../../../scss/variables';` which is not ideal. I'd much rather import the same exact line no matter where I am.

Is there a simple `@import` that I just missed trying? I've tried these and can't get it to work:

```
app/scss/variables
/app/scss/variables
scss/variables
/scss/variables
/src/app/scss/variables
src/app/scss/variables
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I solved it by inserting the following at the top of my scss file.

```
@import '~assets/scss/variables';
```

I hope this helps you and others.

Comment: You added that to a component? My IDE and Angular-Cli both are saying that path doesn't exist. My folder structure is exactly the same as the example above.

Comment: I added that in my scss file. My structure is essentially the same as yours. I'm using VSCode. No errors. Notice the '~';

Answer (score 0):

Best way you should do is importing your global sass into angular-cli.json file. Check the styles section and add your file there.